# Updating SQL records from textboxes using ASP.Net 2010

Tags: asp.net

I am passing a variable (record ID) from a form that has a data grid to a different webform so that I can update that specific record. My issue comes when I try to update the record. The value of the textboxes change to the new data but the program is passing the values of the textboxes before changes take place.
My quick solution was to add postback to the button just to check if this would make a difference. This worked fine only if I hard coded the record ID field, postback erases the parameter I am passing to the new form.

Does anyone have an idea how to address this? As you can see, I am new to ASP.Net.

This is my ASP code for the button:

`asp:Button ID="btnSaveChanges" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" postbackurl="~/EditContact.aspx"  Width="101px"`

And here is the VB Code I have to update the record:

```
   Dim tempContactID As String = Request.QueryString().ToString
   Dim objConnection As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim objCmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String

    'Connection String to Database
    strConnection = "provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=HP-G640;Database=Contacts;user ID=contactsUser;password=password;"

    objConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
    objConnection.ConnectionString = strConnection

    objConnection.Open()


    strSQL = "update ContactDetails set ContactFirstName = '" & txtFirstName.Text & "', ContactMiddleName = '" & txtMiddleName.Text & "',ContactLastName = '" & txtLastName.Text & "', ContactAddress = '" & txtAddress.Text & "', ContactCity = '" & txtCity.Text & "', ContactState = '" & txtState.Text & "', ContactZipCode = '" & txtZipCode.Text & "', ContactPhone = '" & txtHomePhone.Text & "', ContactCell = '" & txtCell.Text & "', ContactEmail='" & txtEmail.Text & "'  where ContactID = 6"
    objCmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, objConnection)

    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'Close Connection
    objConnection.Close()
    Response.Write("Record updated successfully")
```

Comment: "the program is passing the values of the textboxes before changes take place." - I'm not quite clear what you mean by this. Are you doing your update in the webform? I think we need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use an event instead of postback url on your button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveChanges" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="btnSaveChanges_Click"
    Width="101px" />
```

code behind

```
void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do your work
    }
```

Comment: Page_Load happens before events. Use `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`